# unsignedIntValue vs intValue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Consider the code below

```
id j = @"123";
NSUInteger a = [j unsignedIntValue]; // not working
NSUInteger b = [j intValue]; // works
```

Why when converting an object of NSString to unsigned integer, only `intValue` works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `unsignedIntValue` is a method of `NSNumber`, while `intValue` is present in both `NSNumber` and `NSString`.

Answer (score 3):

`unsignedIntValue` is a method of class `NSNumber` and not `NSString`.

So, when you will call `unsignedIntValue` on the object of `NSString`, it will not able to link your object and function call.